# Disabling individual cookies for specific websites in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I recently started managing my passwords with keepass. The WebAutoType plugin is used to fill in fields in Chrome.

One annoying problem is that Chrome often automatically fills in the username, and then I have to delete that.

Many of these unwanted auto-fills can be removed by shift-delete. But some remain.

I have found that the problem are cookies. So my next task is to delete and disable individual cookies for individual websites. Is this possible at all with Chrome?

Comment: I use KeePass for many passwords. But if Browser Autofill has the correct password, I let Browser Autfill work.  That is, I blend the two ideas. Works fine.

Comment: @John As I understand things, the point of using KeePass is to avoid using browser autofill.  Browser autofill is not safe enough to keep passwords.  Or am I missing someting?

Comment: I understand your idea - I just think it is too difficult to implement. Other password Apps have the same issue. It is not unique to Kee Pass.

Comment: Also Chrome and Edge password encryption is very good and does prevent people from trying to hack good passwords. Overall, I just use both Chromium and KeePass passwords.

Comment: @John As you put it, one does not need KeePass at all.  99.5% of my passwords are typed in the browser.  Which makes me (a non-expert) wondering, why are people using KeePass at all.

Comment: I keep all my passwords in KeyPass as well as a folder in KeyPass with many other important and secure items. I use KeyPass C on my iPhone and sync the KeyPass secure export with my iPhone. This has helped my enormously. There is room for both (browser and KeyPass) and I use both all the time.

Comment: @John OK, I think this works well for you, I will still transfer all my passwords to KeePass and use them from there.  Hopefully there is a way to block individual cookies.

Comment: If you only use one browser, period, then the browser password manager may be sufficient. If you use multiple browsers and also login to non-web applications and wish to store those creds, a password manager is better. I would not mix both though, as keeping passwords synced correctly in multiple places can be an issue. Get one method working correctly, and disable the function in other places is my recommendation.